# Is coRE closed under concatenation?

Tags: computability, turing-machines

I know that RE is closed under union, intersection, and concatenation (but not complement). It is likewise easy to show that coRE is closed under union and intersection (but not complement). What about concatenation? I don't even know which way to conjecture...

Comment: What is the concatenation of two sets of integers?

Comment: @BartoszBednarczyk: OP is talking about sets of finite words over an alphabet. But since you ask, the concatenation of 42 and 23 is 4223.

Comment: Yes. Or, alternatively, one could set up a 1-to-1 correspondence between strings and integers (in any way you like), and that extends the concatenation operation from strings to integers.

Comment: But languages are neither integers nor strings, but *sets* thereof. Concatenation on sets of strings is, apparently, in this context defined by $L_0\cdot L_1=\{w_0\cdot w_1:w_0\in L_0,w_1\in L_1\}$.

Comment: Yes, this is the standard definition given in every textbook.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes coRE is closed under concatenation:

Let $L_1, L_2$ be coRE, witnessed by Turing Machines $M_1,M_2$ whose domain is the complement of $L_1,L_2$ respectively.

We then build a Turing Machine $M$ whose domain is the complement of $L_1\cdot L_2$: on input $u$, $M$ will enumerate the finitely many ways to decompose $u$ into $u_1u_2$, and for each of them run $M_1$ on $u_1$ and $M_2$ on $u_2$ in parallel. If one of the machines halts, it means that the decomposition is not a witness that $u$ is in $L_1\cdot  L_2$, and $M$ continues with the next decomposition. The machine $M$ will halt once all decompositions have been tried. Therefore, $M$ does not halt on $u$ if and only if $u\in L_1\cdot L_2$.

Comment: Very nice! Should've seen that myself...